# Data Studio Authentication: difference between checkForValidCreds and validateCredentials

Tags: google-apps-script, looker-studio

On the Data Studio authentication documentation (https://developers.google.com/datastudio/connector/auth), there are two functions that need to be defined which I am confused by.

In the setCredentials function, it says to call a checkForValidCreds function:

```
  // Optional
  // Check if the provided username and token are valid through a
  // call to your service. You would have to have a `checkForValidCreds`
  // function defined for this to work.
  var validCreds = checkForValidCreds(username, token);
```

Meanwhile, in the isAuthValid function, you are asked to define a similar function called validateCredentials:

```
  // This assumes you have a validateCredentials function that
  // can validate if the userName and token are correct.
  return validateCredentials(userName, token);
```

Are these user-defined functions different from each other?  If so, what are the differences I need to know when defining them?

Answer (score 1):

The only function names that need to be constant are listed in the [auth page](https://developers.google.com/datastudio/connector/auth#isauthvalid). Related to your question, as long as you define `isAuthValid()`, you should be good to go. `checkForValidCreds` and `validateCredentials` are just two implementation of the same method used inside `isAuthValid()`. You can name these anything as long as they are correctly referenced within `isAuthValid()`.